# How do I give a 'submit' button more than one action in php?

Tags: php, forms, function, button, form-submit

I have a form that on submit  I want it to do two things:
1) store values in a database
2) write $_POST values to a pdf

I have a script for the database writes and it works on its own. I have another script for the write to PDF and it too works fine on its own.

However, when i try to call one function at the end of the other, the submit action only performs one of the actions. How can  I resolve this. I would like my button to execute both store.php and makepdf.php

Currently, I can only specify one form in the action tag of my form.

EDIT: I am adding the scripts here.

Here is my store.db file (concatenated for length limits):

```
<?php

   $dbhost = 'localhost';
   $dbuser = '';
   $dbpass = '';

// GET ALL THE VARIABLES FROM THE FORM

     $FirstName= $_POST['firstname']?$_POST['firstname']:'0';
     $LastName= $_POST['lastname']?$_POST['lastname']:'0'; 
     $Email= $_POST['email']?$_POST['email']:'0'; 
     $idn= $_POST['idn']; 

   $conn = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass);

   if(! $conn ) {
      die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
   }

   $sql1 = "INSERT INTO borrower(FirstName,LastName,Email,ssn) VALUES('".$FirstName."','".$LastName."','".$Email."','".$idn.");
   mysql_select_db('db');
   $retval1 = mysql_query( $sql1, $conn );

   }

//Test successs 
   //echo "Successful"  

?>
```

Here is my makepdf.php :

```
<?php 

function pdfMaker() {
include('fpdf/fpdf.php'); 
include('fpdi/fpdi.php'); 

$FirstName;
$LastName;
$Email;
$IDNumber;



// initiate FPDI 
$pdf =& new FPDI(); 
// add a page 
$pdf->AddPage(); 
// set the sourcefile 
$pdf->setSourceFile('rcpp1.pdf'); 
// import page 1 
$tplIdx = $pdf->importPage(1); 
// use the imported page as the template 
$pdf->useTemplate($tplIdx, 0, 0); 

// now write some text above the imported page 
$pdf->SetFont('Times', '', 9); 
$pdf->SetTextColor(0,0,153); 

// Top Left stuff
$pdf->SetXY(9, 38); 
$pdf->Write(0, $Firstaname.$LastName.$Email.$IDNumber); 

$pdf->Output(($Firsname."_".$Lastname.'file.pdf'), 'D'); 

}

pdfMaker();

?>
```

And here is my form:

```
<form class="form-horizontal" method="post" action="">
<fieldset>

<!-- Text input-->
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="firstname">First Name</label>  
  <div class="col-md-4">
  <input id="firstname" name="firstname" type="text" placeholder="" class="form-control input-md">

  </div>
</div>

<!-- Text input-->
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="lastname">Last</label>  
  <div class="col-md-4">
  <input id="lastname" name="lastname" type="text" placeholder="" class="form-control input-md">

  </div>
</div>

<!-- Text input-->
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="email">Email</label>  
  <div class="col-md-4">
  <input id="email" name="email" type="text" placeholder="" class="form-control input-md">

  </div>
</div>

<!-- Text input-->
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="idn">ID#</label>  
  <div class="col-md-4">
  <input id="idn" name="idn" type="text" placeholder="" class="form-control input-md">

  </div>
</div>

</fieldset>
</form>
```

Again, when i add either php script to the action tag in the form, each function fine seperately. But if try to add one function to the other script or call it from the other, it only executes one and stops.

Comment: Without being able to see your code we can only speculate....which we do not do really well.

Comment: Shoul I include all three scripts?

Comment: forms can only submit to one url at a time. why do you want the "submit button" to do two different things? isn't that the job of whatever the form is submitting to? it's trivial to have that script be `<?php job1(); job2(); ?>`

Comment: I have updated with my scripts.

Answer (score 0):

are you referring to `<form action="/uri" >` ?

how about `<form action="/path/to/do_two_things.php" >` ?

or

```
<form action="/path/my_form_handler.php">
    <input type="submit" name="dowhat" value="Do action A" />
    <input type="submit" name="dowhat" value="Do action B" />
</form>

<?php
if ($_POST['dowhat'] == "Do action A") {
    // something
    // even more than one thing
} else {
    // something else
    // etc
}
?>
```

Answer (score -1):

Simply **include one script in another** in PHP:

Try this in your `store.php` script:

```
include("makepdf.php");
```

FYI, you can also call one script from another, but you will need to pass the post params along with the file name like so:

```
file_get_contents("makepdf.php?param1=".$_POST['param1']."&param2=".$_POST['param2']);
```

Comment: I don't know who downvoted you, I don't think it was me.  I have updated with my scripts.

Comment: Don't worry about it. Did you try the include?